# What is the proper technique for debugging signed android apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, apk

I wonder if someone can point me in the right directions.  I have followed some procedures from similar posts about debugging signed apk using eclipse Attach process method.

I can attach fine by selecting the known running app and clicking on the green bug (?) icon.  So now I can stop break points.  However for some reason I am never able to run at the startup MAIN activity.

This makes sense as the app is already running and proceeded way past MAIN activity by the time I am able to see it, select it, attach to it.  So I figure it's a race you will always be a little behind in.  Anyone know of a solution to this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the app supports orientation changes, you could simply attach, then rotate the device and catch the lifecycle callback you're wanting to debug.  You might also consider Debug.waitForDebugger if you own the code.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to debug a "debug version" of the app?

Comment: Michael, can you explain how Debug.waitForDebugger works?  Yes we have access to the code.